# Browserless, ant-task-oriented Javascript Unit Testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, build-automation, maven-1

I'm looking for a javascript unit test framework that I can use as part of my automated maven build. This CANNOT use an actual browser, and it MUST be fully browserless.

I've tried looking at a few posts on SO, but none seem to meet my needs. Is there such a javascript unit tester? I'm anxious to find out.

Comment: You may be able to test pure JavaScript, but you won't be able to test any code that manipulates the DOM without something that, at the very least, simulates the DOM interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was trying to solve the same problem. It seems, that this is not as common, as one might think from our perspective.

[RhinoUnit](http://code.google.com/p/rhinounit/) looks very good.

If you need browser capabilities within Rhino, take a look at

- http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/
- http://groups.google.com/group/envjs
- http://github.com/thatcher/env-js/tree/master

Answer (score 3):

There are two projects called JSUnit ([www.jsunit.net](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit)) and ([jsunit.berlios.de](http://jsunit.berlios.de/)). The latter is designed to work with [Rhino and Maven](http://jsunit.berlios.de/maven2.html).  Note that there will be browser-specific problems that such tests will not discover, but it should help with basic functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a JavaScript unit testing framework, though I'm sure there is one. But I would probably look towards Rhino as JS interpreter.

http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

If your JS references any of the browser/DOM you'll also need to mock/stub those...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JSunit?

Comment: Does it not require a browser?

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK, javascript is a language specifically designed to run in the browser.

Have you considereds [j-unit](http://www.junit.org/) tests? They do still run in the browser however.

Comment: JavaScript started life in a browser, but is emphatically *not* a browser-only language. Within just a couple of years of its inception it was being used in non-browser environments, and continues to be. Its specification[1] is general, not browser-specific. It's a scripting language in any number of software packages, a server-side language for dynamic web sites, a command shell scripting language, etc., etc.

[1] http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm